# Ajax Issues Json Multiple Tables, Possible Easy fix

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

So i've ran into an issue again with my coding.

I'm trying to get multiple tables working with different JSON Calls. Any ideas what to do?

Heres the code below

```
    <table class="pull-left table table-fill">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-hover">Name</th>
    <th class="table-hover">Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
    </body>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: 'API URL HERE',
      success: function (json) {
           //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
           for(var i =0;i < json.results.collection1.length;i++) {
             var title = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.text;
             var href = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.href;
             var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='"+href+"'>Link</button>";
             $("table").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
    $("table").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
                 location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
                             });
                }
          },
     error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
     }
   });
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        <table class="pull-left table table-fill">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-hover">Name</th>
    <th class="table-hover">Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
    </body>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: 'API URL HERE',
      success: function (json) {
           //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
           for(var i =0;i < json.results.collection1.length;i++) {
             var title = json.results.collection1[i].property1.text;
             var href = json.results.collection1[i].property1.href;
             var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='"+href+"'>Link</button>";
             $("table").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
            $("table").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
});
                  }

          },
     error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
           }
                });
    </script>
```

sorry about the wild code, it would turn into code. I thought it was just as easy as turning the "table" in the table class into something random to make the data pull in but its still not working.

Comment: give the tables  ID's. `$('table')` will find all tables in a page

Comment: Once given the table id's i then need to? change the '$('table')' to that id? So for example '<table id=pear>' the '$('pear')' would suffice?

Comment: must use proper jQuery selector for each table based on the id's

Comment: so like htis? $('table [data-name=my_table]');

Comment: No, suggest you study how jQuery selectors work.